how to mock Date in Jun 1, 2024, 8:07:29.920 PM format
I want to mock a date object in Jun 1, 2024, 8:07:29.920 PM format in java 11.
Can anyone please help here.
I tried using the code below:
Date currentDate = new Date();
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(currentDate.getTime()), ZoneId.of("UTC"));
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(odt.getYear(), odt.getMonthValue(), odt.getDayOfMonth(), 6, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
Date startDate = Date.from(zonedDateTime.toInstant());
Mockito.when(mockPriceMap.get("startDate")).thenReturn(startDate);

But this is generating date in this format: Tue Aug 06 15:30:00 IST 2024
whereas my requirement is in this format: Jun 1, 2024, 8:07:29.920 PM
My requirement is, I have a date value stored in Firestore DB in this format: Jun 1, 2024, 8:07:29.920 PM, and I would need to fetch this from Firestore DB and have validations against it in my Java code. I am seeking help in fetching this date value (not necessarily date) can have object, string whatever. and then parsing it for the validations against current date.

A Date object just represents an instant in time. It doesn't have a format, or a time zone. See my article here for more details: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/

(This is a bit like saying "I have a requirement to create an int value with a hex format, but whatever I do it's got a decimal format." If you understand why that requirement doesn't make sense, then apply it to java.util.Date.)

Do you really need a Date object or a String? Those are different… You can format a Date (or OffsetDateTime, ZonedDateTime etc.) as String in different formats, but the values of the object will stay the same. So what exactly is your requirement?

Consider migrating your code fully to java.time, the modern Java date and time API. The Date class that you seem to be returning had bad design problems and has been outdated the last 10 years.

What made you think that you need a Date in a particular format? (As others have said, you are asking the impossible there.)

BTW I find the following way of obtaining your ZonedDateTime clearer and simpler: YearMonth.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).atDay(6).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")).

LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("Jun 1, 2024, 8:07:29.920 PM", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d, yyyy, h:mm:ss.SSS a"));

This doesn't parse and giving an error, parseException : java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Jun 1, 2024, 8:07:29.920 PM' could not be parsed at index 25

Okay , so my requirement is I have a date value stored in Firestore DB in this format. Jun 1, 2024, 8:07:29.920 PM and I would need to fetch this from firestore DB, and have validations against it in my java code. I am seeking help in fetching this date value( not necessarily date) can have object , string whatever. and then parsing it for the validations against current date. Does this makes sense now.

little correction (for non-english locales): LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("Jun 1, 2024, 8:07:29.920 PM", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d, yyyy, h:mm:ss.SSS a", Locale.US)); (or ..., Locale.ROOT));or ..., Locale.ENGLISH)); or whatever appropriate for the given string - BTW what type is the date saved as? String/CHAR or some kind of TIME/DATE?)

correction also for UK Locales (index 25 - use lowercase AM/PM)

Thanks for the clarification, it really helps. Please always add further information to the question itself rather than in comments so we have everything in one place. I am sorry that I don’t know Firestore.

In order to compare a date and time such as Jun 1, 2024, 8:07:29.920 PM with the current moment, you first need to know which time zone was assumed. In the different time zones of the earth June 1 at 8 PM denotes different times in a span of 24 hours or more (that’s true).


Date currentDate = new Date();

a) Which Date? The legacy date-time classes unfortunately bundle two classes with the same name Date: java.util.Date & java.sql.Date.
b) Don’t! Do not use either Date class. They are tragically flawed in numerous ways. They are part of the date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern java.time classes defined in JSR 310.
The java.util.Date class was replaced with java.time.Instant.
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment as seen with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

Avoid both Date classes, as well as Calendar, SimpleDateFormat, and the other legacy date-time classes. Use only java.time classes.
If handed a java.util.Date class, immediate convert to java.time class via the new to…/from… conversion methods added to the old classes.
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;

The java.sql.Date class was replaced by java.time.LocalDate.
ZoneId zTunis = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
LocalDate todayTunis = LocalDate.now( zTunis ) ;

If handed a java.sql.Date object, immediately convert to java.time by calling toLocalDate.
LocalDate localDate = myJavaSqlDate.toLocalDate() ;

Your code:
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(currentDate.getTime()), ZoneId.of("UTC"));

… is much too complicated. No need for a count of milliseconds since epoch reference. Just call java.util.Date#toInstant — that’s why the new method was added to the old class: myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() as shown above.
Your code:
OffsetDateTime odt = …

… is irrelevant and unhelpful. The Instant class already has an offset of zero.
Your code:
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = …

… is irrelevant. Both java.time.Instant and java.util.Date represent a moment, a point on the timeline, as seen from an offset of zero. Time zone is not at all helpful here.
FYI, definitions:

An offset is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind the temporal meridian of UTC.
A time zone is a named history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region as decided by their politicians.

According to the documentation, Firestore represents date-time types to the microsecond. The java.time types resolve to the finer granularity of nanoseconds. So you may should truncate to microseconds to eliminate nanoseconds, as a habit.
Instant instantTruncated = instant.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MICROS ) ;

I cannot find any details in the Firestore documentation about its date and time types, so I cannot provide more assistance.
